How to update multiple array of object fields in the most efficient manner using mongoose
Let's  say I have the following data document in Mongo:
{ id: '1',
  collaborators: [ 
   { name: "name 1",
     email: "email 1",
     rating: null
   },
   { name: "name 2",
     email: "email 2",
     rating: null
   }],
   social: [
   { type: "type A",
     message: "message A",
     response: false
   },
   { type: "type B",
     message: "message B",
     response: false
   }]
}

and I need to update both email 1 and type B objects in their respective arrays from the returned data.
I know I can run a positional operator update in two separate calls i.e. something like:
await model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1, collaborators.email: "email1"}, {$set: { "collaborators.$.rating: 5"}})
await model.findOneAndUpdate({_id: 1, social.type: "typeB"}, {$set: { "social.$.response: true"}})

and I could probably use bulkWrite to make it more efficient, as I'll end up with a lot more of these in production, but can I just run one query to update both arrays ?

Did you try using array filters?

Here is an example of arrayFilters as suggested by @Joe

@ray You may as well post that as an answer :-) Otherwise, it stays open and unanswered. Or we close it as rtfm.

@aneroid Does "rtfm" means the option of "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"? That would be my preferred close reason.

@ray Yeah, those older close reasons have been removed. So "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" is the closest to ignore, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers. You may as well post it as an answer. Because OP did at least show what they tried as the alternative, so effort was put in. (As opposed to "here's my data, how do I do this, no MRE provided" which we see so often.)

@aneroid I agree it is not a bad question. I just feel the solution is trivial so I don't want to scam rep with an answer :)

@ray Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. How do I set your comment as the correct answer ?

@ray Nah, go for it :-) OP put in the effort and future readers may not read all the comments here. Ideally, we should find a duplicate which does something very similar. That can be hard when it's for something as trivial. But I'd say arrayFilters is not that well understood/remembered by those less familiar with MongoDB, so if we can't find a dupe, you should post the answer. And we make this canon.

Credit goes to @joe for bringing up the idea of using arrayFilters
You can specify matched element position through the usage of arrayFilters and update the referenced element.
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "collaborators.$[c].rating": 5,
    "social.$[s].response": true
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "c.email": "email 1"
    },
    {
      "s.type": "type B"
    }
  ]
})

Mongo Playground

One of the side notes is that you may want to consider refactoring the schema to separate collaborators and social into different documents/collections. It could be contradicting your requirement of minimizing db calls but they seem like independent information from the context I observed in the post. Separating them can bring benefits of simpler code and potential performance boost through indexing.
